# index.html:308 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or

Tags: javascript, drawimage

getting
index.html:308 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.

```
$("#file-picker")[0].onchange = function() {
        $("#EnterWrapper").hide();
        $(".ContainerWrapper").show();
        var c = document.getElementsByClassName('demo-canvas');
        var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
        img = $("#file-picker")[0];
        console.log(typeof img[this.spriteCostumeCount])
        ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 150, 180);
};
```

Comment: `img` is a reference to the input element. You've to read the content of the selected file, and then pass that to `drawImage` method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Don't use a `FileReader` for that, simply create an `ImageBitmap` from your `File`: convert your `onchange` handler to an `async` function and then `img = await createImageBitmap($("#file-picker")[0].files[0]);`